# Python: How can I return a function as True and apply it to an earlier function to change the true/false statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm just starting out with Python 2 and programming in general and decided to make a text adventure for a bit of practice, but I'm completely stuck on *title*.

This is the code so far. I'm pretty much completely guessing the whole True/False stuff, but what I'm trying to work out is: when you enter the `"viewing_room"` you come across a locked door, but if you go to the `"lab_room"` and get the keycard from the body you can open it.

I am trying to make it so that the locked door is False, but when you collect the keycard, it changes to True and the door becomes unlocked. I appreciate any help, thanks!

```
prompt = "> "
decision = "What do you do?"
not_assigned = "Say wa?"
def engine_room():
    print "You are in a dark room with the sound of moaning engines."
    print "You see a corridor to your left and one to your right and an elevator straight ahead of you."
    print decision
    choice = raw_input(prompt)
    if choice == "go left":
        viewing_room()
    elif choice == "go right":
        right_corridor_dead_end()
    elif choice == "use elevator":
        print "you get in the elevator and go up."
        main_hallway()
    else:
        print not_assigned
        engine_room()

def right_corridor_dead_end():
    print "You walk down the corridor only to be blocked by a collapsed ceiling."
    print decision
    choice = raw_input(prompt)      
    if choice == "go back":
        engine_room()           
    else:
        print not_assigned

def viewing_room(): 
    print "You walk down the corridor and enter and a large room with a window covering the size of the wall."
    print "Straight ahead is another door"
    print decision
    choice = raw_input(prompt)
    if search_body() == False:
        if choice == "open door":
            print "The door is locked"
            viewing_room()
        elif choice == "go back":
            engine_room()
        else:
            print not_assigned
    if search_body() == True:
        if choice == "open door":
            print "The door opens you walk through"
            storage_room()
        else:
            print not_assigned
            viewing_room()

def main_hallway():
        print "You enter a large brightly lit room with 3 rooms connected to it and another elevator straight ahead."
        print "The rooms are named, the two on the left are the armoury and lab rooms and to the right are the cabins."
        print decision
        choice = raw_input(prompt)
        if choice == "go to lab room":
            lab_room()
        elif choice == "go back":
            engine_room()

def lab_room():
    print "You enter the lab room which is cluttered with unexplainable machines."
    print "To the back of the room you see the dead body of a man with no obvious cause"
    print "He might have something useful on him"
    print decision
    choice = raw_input(prompt)  
    if choice == "search body":
        search_body()
    elif choice == "go back":
        main_hallway()

def search_body():
    print "You find a keycard that says 'storage' on it."
    return True 
    lab_room()

engine_room()
```

Comment: `lab_room()` is unreachable in `search_body` after your return statement

Comment: You should take a look into class instead of functions.

Comment: You need to be able to store state somehow. Typically this is done with objects, and this is really a prime example of when to use object oriented programming. Look into OOP in Python.

Comment: `class` ic: check your `self` before you wreck your `self` ..... `oop` s

Comment: The problem is that you need to keep the state of the game as you go. Using classes is common, but you could also create a dict that has key/value pairs that keep track of which features are enabled / disabled. That dict could be a global variable, or better, it could be passed to the functions. This is very similar to a class that holds the state but is a bit more decoupled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look into classes. If you make games Object oriented programming is a better way to do it.

When you get used to classes, it gets easier to make games.

Here is an example of your game, as a class object

```
prompt = "> "
decision = "What do you do?"
not_assigned = "Say wa?"

class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.bodySearched = False
        self.engine_room()

    def engine_room(self):
        print "You are in a dark room with the sound of moaning engines."
        print "You see a corridor to your left and one to your right and an elevator straight ahead of you."
        print decision
        self.choice = raw_input(prompt)

        if self.choice == "go left":
            self.viewing_room()

        elif self.choice == "go right":
            self.right_corridor_dead_end()

        elif self.choice == "use elevator":
            print "you get in the elevator and go up."
            self.main_hallway()

        else:
            print not_assigned
            self.engine_room()


    def right_corridor_dead_end(self):
        print "You walk down the corridor only to be blocked by a collapsed ceiling."
        print decision
        self.choice = raw_input(prompt)

        if choice == "go back":
            self.engine_room()

        else:
            print not_assigned

    def viewing_room(self): 
        print "You walk down the corridor and enter and a large room with a window covering the size of the wall."
        print "Straight ahead is another door"
        print decision
        self.choice = raw_input(prompt)

        if not self.bodySearched:
            if self.choice == "open door":
                print "The door is locked"
                self.viewing_room()

            elif self.choice == "go back":
                self.engine_room()

            else:
                print not_assigned

        if self.bodySearched:
            if self.choice == "open door":
                print "The door opens you walk through"
                self.storage_room()

            else:
                print not_assigned
                self.viewing_room()


    def main_hallway(self):
            print "You enter a large brightly lit room with 3 rooms connected to it and another elevator straight ahead."
            print "The rooms are named, the two on the left are the armoury and lab rooms and to the right are the cabins."
            print decision
            self.choice = raw_input(prompt)

            if choice == "go to lab room":
                self.lab_room()

            elif choice == "go back":
                self.engine_room()



    def lab_room(self):
        print "You enter the lab room which is cluttered with unexplainable machines."
        print "To the back of the room you see the dead body of a man with no obvious cause"
        print "He might have something useful on him"
        print decision
        self.choice = raw_input(prompt)

        if self.choice == "search body":
            self.bodySearched = True
            print "You find a keycard that says 'storage' on it."
            self.lab_room()

        elif self.choice == "go back":
            self.main_hallway()

newGame = Game()
```

Now newGame is an object of the type Game, and will remember its states. 
The def **init**(self) is a method that will be called when ever you create a new object of that class. And you can create as many Game objects as you want, the name newGame or whatever you call the new object will replace self. So player1.searchedBody might be true while player2.searchedBody might be false. This is very handy.

Comment: why does this work better? Im assuming self. is referring to the player, does it maintain their state, and if so why is it not as easy to code without using a class? Could you also explain what the def __init__(self): function is doing?

Comment: Easier might be the wrong way to put it. But if you use class each object has its methods, like a player would have, dealDamage and takeDamage move jump etc. You could also make it with dictionaries and functions as some one menitoned

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems to me this is not a Python question but rather a general programming question. You need some way to store your program's state - specifically, whether the body has been searched before or not. You should read a little bit about [state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), or look into passing stateful objects around between your different functions (maybe a "Player" or "Character" object which maintains some kind of state).

BTW when comparing to a boolean value in if, you can simply do:

```
if search_body():
    pass
```

or:

```
if not search_body():
    pass
```

Rather than comparing to `True` or `False`.

Comment: looking into it now actually but could you explain to me what pass is doing, a description I have of it says, "This block is empty", I know what a block is (or maybe just not well enough) but what does that even mean or have to do with comparing to a Boolean value?

Comment: @KingSwan - In Python, anytime you have a statement that ends with a colon (like `if`, `for`, `while`, etc.), it expects a block to follow it. That block *must* contain at least one statement. Since it's pretty common to want to define a block that does nothing (for example, if you want to define an "empty" function), the `pass` statement (which does nothing) was created. That way, since a block *must* contain at least one statement, if you want a block that does nothing, you can use the `pass` statement to create a valid block that does nothing.

Comment: @KingSwan - And the reason shevron used `pass` in his example is as a placeholder. If he'd left it out, his answer would have contained invalid Python code (since an `if` statement must always be followed by a block containing at least one statement). In your code, you'd probably do something if the `search_body()` function returned True or False, and so you'd substitute your own code (whatever it was) where he put that `pass` statement.